# Kubuntu stopped notifying of CD and flash disk inserts

Tags: kubuntu

I used to be able to insert a CD or flash disk and Kubuntu 10.04 would pop up a notification allowing me to open up the files on the disk with gwenview etc.

But now, when I insert a CD nothing happens and I have to manually mount it with the mount command.

This is really inconvenient.
I had a look around in the system settings and found "Removable devices" in the advanced section.  All the options are enabled, but it doesn't seem to help.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question.

Make sure the device notifier widget is running.  In my case, it wasn't.